# Errors/exceptions during teardown of flask unit test

Tags: python, flask, pytest, pytest-mock

I am attempting to unit test some methods called by a flask application.  The methods interact with a flask Response object, which I am trying to mock up for testing purposes (I don't want to test the flask Response, it works just fine.)  When I try to run my tests, the tests run as expected but they throw an exception during teardown.

Example code

```
def my_func():
    key = do_some_stuff()
    if key:
        return Response("key", status=200)
    else:
        return Response("key", status=500)
```

Fixture code from conftest.py

```
@pytest.fixture()
def request_context():
    app = create_app()
    return app.test_request_context()
```

Test code

```
def test_get_my_stuff(mocker, request_context):
    def mock_Response_get(*args, **kwargs):
        class mockResponse:
            def __init__(self, status):
                self.status_code = kwargs["status"]

            def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
                return self.status_code

        resp = mockResponse(kwargs["status"])
        return resp


    with request_context:
        mocker.patch("my_func.Response", side_effect=mock_Response_get)
        response = my_modules.get_identity()
        assert response.status_code == 500
```

Results

```
python -m pytest

pytestconfig = <_pytest.config.Config object at 0x7fa1025054c0>

    def _mocker(pytestconfig: Any) -> Generator[MockerFixture, None, None]:
        """
        Return an object that has the same interface to the `mock` module, but
        takes care of automatically undoing all patches after each test method.
        """
        result = MockerFixture(pytestconfig)
        yield result
>       result.stopall()

/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pytest_mock/plugin.py:425: 
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ 
/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pytest_mock/plugin.py:99: in stopall
    p.stop()
/usr/local/lib/python3.9/unittest/mock.py:1553: in stop
    return self.__exit__(None, None, None)
/usr/local/lib/python3.9/unittest/mock.py:1522: in __exit__
    delattr(self.target, self.attribute)
/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/werkzeug/local.py:316: in __get__
    obj = instance._get_current_object()  # type: ignore[misc]
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ 

    def _get_current_object() -> T:
        try:
            obj = local.get()  # type: ignore[union-attr]
        except LookupError:
>           raise RuntimeError(unbound_message) from None
E           RuntimeError: Working outside of request context.
E           
E           This typically means that you attempted to use functionality that needed
E           an active HTTP request. Consult the documentation on testing for
E           information about how to avoid this problem.

/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/werkzeug/local.py:513: RuntimeError
```

To the best of my knowledge, running inside of the with request_context block should ensure against the "working outside of request context" error.

Am I doing something just stupid wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With *flask 2.2.2*, *pytest 7.2.0* and *pytest-mock 3.7.0*, **I cannot reproduce your issue**. That being said, `result.stopall()` of the *mocker* fixture does get called after the test function ends, which also means **after the test request context exits**. You could try following...

1. **Have your fixture create the request context** and `yield` nothing; the `yield` means that your fixture would do a teardown as well, in which it would just exit the context:

```py
@pytest.fixture()
def request_context():
    with create_app().test_request_context():
        yield
```

2. **Change the order** in which fixtures are called (and teared down), putting your fixture before *mocker*. Also, **don't create another test request context** inside the test because that already exists:

```py
def test_get_my_stuff(request_context, mocker):
    def mock_Response_get(*args, **kwargs):
        class mockResponse:
            def __init__(self, status):
                self.status_code = kwargs["status"]

            def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
                return self.status_code

        resp = mockResponse(kwargs["status"])
        return resp

    mocker.patch("tests.app.Response", side_effect=mock_Response_get)
    response = my_func()
    assert response.status_code == 500
```

Comment: Calling my test fixture before mocker did the trick! This had been bugging me for the last week.  **Thank you!**